# How should I configure nginx to run as a reverse proxy websocket server in front of a tcp server?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a tcp server running on `127.0.0.1:1905`

I have configured nginx like this

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream websocket {
        server http://127.0.0.1:1906;
    }

    server {
        listen 8020;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1905;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried opening a socket using:

```
npm install -g wscat
wscat --connect ws://127.0.0.1:1906
```

I get

```
error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1906
```

What am I doing wrong here? I an new with both nginx and web sockets so I don't exactly understand what is happening nor where the problem might lie.

Answer (score 0):

The upstream configuration looks faulty, can you try the bellow,

```
upstream websocket {
   server http://127.0.0.1:1906;
}
server {
    listen 8020;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
    location /webserver {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1905;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
   }
}
```

If you have another server also to be configured, you can configure another upstream or another location as given above for **/webserver**. So **/** will be your socket server and **/webserver** will be the other server(normal http server)

Comment: I tried with your config and still get the same error message. Thank you for your help regardless!

Comment: Have you tried directly accessing 127.0.0.1:1906, it is highly possible that it might not be an issue with Nginx but with the websocket server itself.

Comment: The tcp server is on 127.0.0.1:1906. The following cli command succeeds and returns data from the server: nc localhost 1905

Comment: Your websocket server is running on port 1906 right?

Comment: I have a tcp server running on 1905. I want to connect to the tcp server from a js websockets server. But I have not build the websocket yet. Instead I am testing connecting to the tcp server using the command line tool wscat --connect ws://localhost:1906